# Strange bug parsing XML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml

Can anyone explain this strange behaviour in jQuery? I'm using version 1.5.2.

```
var myxml = '<photo><Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><coordinates>0.153933,52.204674</coordinates></Point><id>24917</id><latitude>52.204674</latitude><longitude>0.153933</longitude><feature>3</feature><caption>No parking.</caption><url>http://www.google.co.uk</url><imageUrl>http://www.google.co.uk</imageUrl><thumbnailUrl>http://www.google.co.uk</thumbnailUrl><thumbnailSizes>60|120|150|180|200|250|300|350|400|400|425|450|500|640</thumbnailSizes></photo>';
console.log($(myxml).find('latitude').text());     
console.log($(myxml).find('caption').text());
```

`latitude` prints the correct value, but `caption` is an empty string.

I've tried using `nodeName` as well, but I get the same result.

Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE: I've also made a jsFiddle to show the behaviour: http://jsfiddle.net/w8Z7z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't telling jQuery you're working with XML.  `caption` is an HTML tag and reserved word, so it is getting confused.  You need to use [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/):

```
var myxml = '...(all that xml)...',
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( myxml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );
console.log($xml.find('caption').text());
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm now getting `$.parseXML is not a function` - any ideas?

Comment: @simon: Are you using jQuery 1.5+ ?  This was added in 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

`Caption` appear to be a reserved word. So, if yo use for example `captionX` works.

Try with other nodeName.

```
var myxml = '<photo><Point srsName="EPSG:4326"><coordinates>0.153933,52.204674</coordinates></Point><id>24917</id><latitude>52.204674</latitude><longitude>0.153933</longitude><feature>3</feature><captionX>No parking.</captionX><url>http://www.google.co.uk</url><imageUrl>http://www.google.co.uk</imageUrl><thumbnailUrl>http://www.google.co.uk</thumbnailUrl><thumbnailSizes>60|120|150|180|200|250|300|350|400|400|425|450|500|640</thumbnailSizes></photo>';
console.log($(myxml).find('captionX').text());
console.log($(myxml).find('latitude').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you parse the xml first and then pass that to jquery it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/w8Z7z/2/

```
var xmldoc=$.parseXML(myxml);  
alert($(xmldoc).find('caption').text());
```

Comment: Excellent. I sort of went down that path (putting an XML declaration in, which didn't work), but this is a much better approach.